# Custom walker decorator

Tags: php, wordpress

I need add to my menu extra icon before text. So I read in documentation that I need implement custom **Walker_Nav_Menu**. After some analyzing, I recognize I could implement my custom walker accord with decorator pattern. I have very small expirience in php especially wordpress. My code works weird. Look at it:

```
class Walker_nav_menu_Decorator extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    public $menu;
    public static $index = 0;
    function __construct() {
        $menu = new Walker_Nav_Menu();
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if($item->title == "Main Menu"){
            $args->before = "TEST";
        }
        echo $index;
        $index+=1;
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args, $id);
    }
}
```

It doesn't echo **$index** at all oO. Additionally add extra "TEST" word before each menu item. How should I do it properly and why this version doesn't work?

My class is in my functions.php file and I'm calling my menu here:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu', 'container' => 'nav' ,'container_class' => 'menu', 'walker' => new Walker_nav_menu_Decorator() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

your $index is static so don't call it directly but by

```
echo self::$index;
    self::$index+=1;
```